# Ignoring exception in command None discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "info" is not found

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

cog.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class ping(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Bot is connected')

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send('Pong')


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(ping(bot))
```

main.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord import app_commands 
import json
import os

file = open('config.json', 'r')
config = json.load(file)

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(config['prefix'], intents=intents, help_command=None)


@bot.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id == config['myid']:
        await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
        await ctx.send('Cogs is loaded...')
    else:
        await ctx.send('You are not a developer.')

@bot.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id == config['myid']:
        await bot.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
        await ctx.send('Cogs is loaded...')
    else:
        await ctx.send('You are not a developer.')

@bot.command()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id == config['myid']:
        await bot.unload_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
        await bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{extension}')
        await ctx.send('Cogs is loaded...')
    else:
        await ctx.send('You are not a developer.')


async def main():
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')


bot.run(config['token'])
```

This is an example of what I want to do in cogs. This is just the bot's response to the user's message.
Erorr:

> ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None
>
> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "ping" is not
> found

I don't know how to fix it. I wonder if you could help me. Thanks`

Comment: Welcome to SO! What message is the user sending to generate this error? Can you provide the full traceback for the error?

Comment: 2023-02-25 11:02:23 ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "ping" is not found

User use command "ping"

Comment: What version of `discord.py` are you using?

Comment: discord.py v2.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a `main` function to load your extensions, **but you're never using it**. Hence, you never load your cogs.

*Also [`load_extension`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=load_extension#discord.ext.commands.Bot.load_extension) is async, and you're not awaiting it.*

Comment: I removed `main` and removed await before `(un)load_extension` but the command is still ignored

Comment: Yes, because you did the exact opposite I told you to do. I said your `main` is **never used**, so removing it isn't gonna do anything. You should **use it** instead......